# Slime: the symbol "HOST-ENT-ADDRESS-TYPE" is not external in the SB-BSD-SOCKETS package

Tags: slime

this is an error message that suddenly prevents me from using Slime:

`; loading #P"/home/vince/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-v2.19/swank-loader.lisp"
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   READ error during COMPILE-FILE:
;

;     The symbol "HOST-ENT-ADDRESS-TYPE" is not external in the SB-BSD-SOCKETS package.
;

;       Line: 117, Column: 76, File-Position: 3633
;

;       Stream: #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM
;                 for "file /home/vince/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-v2.19/swank/sbcl.lisp"
;                 {10065BF923}>
;; 
;; Error compiling /home/vince/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-v2.19/swank/sbcl.lisp:
;;   COMPILE-FILE returned NIL.
;`

Do you have any idea of what's causing it and what I can do ? Thanks.

**update**: happened a second time, supposedly after a quicklisp update.

Comment: Extract and use the 2.18 version of `swank/sbcl.lisp` until this is fixed either in slime or in sbcl (I mean until your distibution upgrades to a newer version of sbcl).

Comment: I got the same error so I did some more research. It seems that the problem (for me) was that I had an old sbcl version (1.0.55). After upgrading to sbcl 1.3.1 the problem disappeared. So I suggest that you either upgrade your sbcl or use the previous version of slime's `swank/sbcl.lisp` as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Any pointers to do that ? I use debian's `sbcl`, there is no newer version. I installed slime with quicklisp (""quicklisp-slime-helper"), nothing new. How can I come back to swank 2.18 ? I tried to delete the `~/quicklisp/.../slime-v2.19` directory but now it complains it's missing. I still wonder why I have a pb now, I didn't update anything :/ thanks !

Comment: In the meanwhile I use [Portacle](https://shinmera.github.io/portacle/)…

Comment: You can grab the file from any commit done before the changes causing problems were made, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/slime/slime/blob/f2ea33ec6a5dbdb76b86cdb415e05c58a3585ff4/swank/sbcl.lisp). But you can get the whole 2.18 version from [here](https://github.com/slime/slime/releases/tag/v2.18). Regarding sbcl: you can install it directly via `sudo apt-get install sbcl` or you can install the binary direcly, [here is how to do it](http://www.sbcl.org/getting.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another fix is to upgrade sbcl.

go to http://www.sbcl.org/platform-table.html, download a binary, run the install script:

```
sudo sh install.sh
```

We can also use linuxbrew: http://linuxbrew.sh/ (it may have to download and compile more stuff).

make sure your emacs will find the location of the new sbcl:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/local/bin/sbcl")  ;; location given by the install script.
```

It worked back with sbcl 1.3.19 and slime 2.19.

Answer (score 1):

The error message was explicit on the error location (`"file /home/vince/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-v2.19/swank/sbcl.lisp"`) and Tamas' suggestion was a good one.

I created a symlink from `slime-v2.18/swank/sbcl.lisp` to its `slime-v2.19` counterpart (I already had those two versions installed) and I can connect again to slime.

Removing the slime v2.19 directory was no good.

I still don't know why this stopped working and I don't have a cleaner workaround.